# Insert an array of UUIDs using Objection.js

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, objection.js

I am attempting to insert a new row into a table with a column defined as an array or UUIDs:

```
alter table medias add column "order" uuid[];
```

I am using Objection.js ORM and attempting to execute the following query:

```
const order = [
  'BFAD6B0D-D3E6-4EB3-B3AB-108244A5DD7F'
]

Medias
  .query()
  .insert({
    order: lit(order.map(id => lit(id).castType('uuid'))).castArray()
  })
```

But the query is malformed and therefore does not execute:

```
INSERT INTO xxx ("order")
    VALUES (ARRAY [
      {"_value":"BFAD6B0D-D3E6-4EB3-B3AB-108244A5DD7F","_cast":"uuid","_toJson":false,"_toArray":false}
    ])
```

As can be seen, the query contains the JSON-stringified representation of the `LiteralBuilder` object and not something that the SQL syntax understands as a typecast.

If I skip casting the individual UUID strings and just cast the whole column into an array, then Postgres rejects the query because the column is of type `uuid[]` but I am attempting to insert the column as `text[]`.

**How can I format this query using Objection.js ORM?**

> My goal is to keep the column definition untouched and be able to insert a Postgres' array of UUIDs using Objection.js, either through its API or via raw query. If this is not currently possible with Objection, I am willing, as a last resort, to re-define the column as `text[]`, but I would like to make sure I really have no other option.